# Passing variables to templates (alternatives to globalizing variables)

Tags: functions, templates, globals

I want to make my WP code simpler (there's some mess within header.php, page.php etc.). So, for example, I want to set something like this global:

```
$foo = get_option('foo');
```

So `$foo` will work properly used anywhere in page.php, header.php, footer.php, loop.php and also within different theme files linked to functions.php (require_once).

I already know two ways of achieving this, both require editing functions.php:

### Global dynamic function

```
function foo() {
   return 'bar';
}
```

### Global constant

```
define('FOO_BAR', 'directory');
```

Do I really need to fire a function in multiple places just for one variable? Isn't it an overkill?

Comment: Isn't `global $foo; $foo = 'bar';` and then in your template `echo $foo;` sufficient enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use this function:

```
set_query_var('foo', $foo);
```

WP will extract and expose all query variables in every template it loads, so you will be able to access it as `$foo`

Comment: This is brilliant! :)